# PHP : inheritance logical (extends)

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony1

This may sound as a non related coding question but it's directly related :

**The facts:** I've developped a website (with symfony) which allows players to search for a team (like a job board). It makes one module only.

**The problems** I want the website to be even more accurate and make a custom form for each players depending on the game (for example, for those who play "league of legends" they'll have 3 more informations to fill up....)

**The solutions?**

- One module per game (example: http://pastie.org/private/cl48jsrjreukyjmj7jrk8a).

I'm currently developping 1 module per game in order to take in consideration the specific criteria for specific games.

*Advantages :*
The player enters the informations in relation with his game and does not see/interact the other criteria

*Disavantages:* 
90% of the code are the same between each modules. It takes more time.

---

- **Inheritance**

I never played with that before so i don't know if it's possible in my case to stick with 1 module for the entire game collection AND taking in consideration the specific criterias for games. In that case it would mean to have 1 template per game and displaying the right template with the right accessors like 
(`$this->getCV()->getPseudo();` / `$this->getCV()->getGame()->getSpecificCriteria1();`)

Comment: sounds reasonable, not repeating yourself is always a good idea. but what's your question? :)

Comment: If inheritance allows me to keep 1 module for whatever games i have :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have read your question correctly, you want to show additional fields for each specific game.

**Solution 1**

Create a 2 form process. After your first form, you could redirect the user to a second form which depends on their answers. To do this, in your first form, use a redirect to send the user to a game-specific second form.

**Solution 2**

Pass the name of the game to the template and show a customised partial for the extra form fields. For this you will need a Url with a game parameter like this:

www.example.com/form/show/:game_identifier

Then in your action, read the parameter and pass it to your template.
In the template, show a partial dependant on the game that was passed through. So only show the extra fields if a specific game was chosen before hand.

There are further ways to accomplish this but these 2 sprung to mind first.

Comment: thanks, that confirms what i was thinking of (rendering partials according to the games)